# Actionscript 3 game: object respawning

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im trying to make a simple game in AS3 where a player eats as many balls as possible. i dont know how to code very well and im having trouble trying to add a new ball to the stage every time one is eaten. 
this is the code i have in main.as at the moment.

```
    private var startX:Number = 512;
    private var startY:Number = 384;
    private var speed:Number = 8;
    var player1;
    var player2;
    var player3;
    var theBall; 
    player1 = new player(50,384, 1);
    player2 = new player(944,384,2);
    player3 = new player(488,84,3);
    stage.addChild(player1);
    stage.addChild(player2);
    stage.addChild(player3);

    if(theBall.hitTestObject(player1) || theBall.hitTestObject(player2) || theBall.hitTestObject(player3))
        {
            //removes the ball from the stage
            trace("a player has eaten a ball");
            stage.removeChild(theBall);
            //adds new ball
            //stage.addChild(theBall);
            //reset x and y
            startX = Math.random()*speed-speed/2;
            startY = Math.random()*speed-speed/2;
        }
```

In the ball.as ive specified how the ball should move randomly, start in the center of the stage and bounce off walls.

no errors appear, the code just doesnt work. how do you make a new ball re spawn in the center of the stage when one is eaten? do i declare this where i tried to in the main, or in the ball.as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a "ball" Object, in the way you have a "player" Object, then...

```
        //removes the ball from the stage
        trace("a player has eaten a ball");
        stage.removeChild(theBall);
        //reset x and y
        startX = Math.random()*speed-speed/2;
        startY = Math.random()*speed-speed/2;
        //adds new ball
        theBall = new ball();
        theBall.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
        theBall.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
        stage.addChild( theBall );
```

You reuse the "theBall" variable, since you've removed the eaten instance from the stage.  The old "theBall" instance is thrown out with stage.removeChild(theBall), and then you make a new one and add that new one to the stage.

Comment: Thankyou! i have the ball object setup the exact same way so this worked perfectly!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Before your code, if the BALL isn't called and prepared for your stage. It might not work.

In your Library, check the movie_clip that contain the ball... And under the row "AS LINKAGE" next to the name of the Movie Clipe... You should call it for example "BALL_TEST"

In your AS3 code :

Add this before your code

```
var ball_bounce:BALL_TEST = new BALL_TEST();
```

Then your code

If i did correctly understand your question...

Kind regards

Comment: oh sorry i didnt mention it, but yeah i set the ''ball'' up ready for the stage. thankyou for helping though! really appreciated :)

Comment: No problem. Try to update your full code. Like this everyone can help easily. Take care. Will check your code. 

BTW do you have any error or compiling issue?

Comment: oh true yeah sorry i didnt know i was missing important elements but yeah thankyou will do next time :)
I do have one error but its connected to stage.removeChild(theBall);

ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at main/checkForCollision()
im really bad with action script but the ball disappears from the stage like i wanted it to so i just ignored the error aha

Comment: Could you provide by Private message your FLA, with your Embed files and Font. I can check it out. Cause like this for me it's quite difficult to help you out... I ain't a pro :p

Comment: haha yeah i understand! thankyou for helping! how do i private message on here? :/ sorry i just started using it yesterday ahah